# How to Implement Caching using JQuery at Client Side Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I want to use the values of one page in another page using cache. Can any one suggest me how to use cache using jQuery?

After searching on several sites, I found this link : http://markdaggett.com/blog/2012/03/28/client-side-request-caching-with-javascript/. It uses a `$.Cache.add(key,value);` method.

When I used this in my aspx page it is throwing an error. Do I need to add any files to achieve cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a value in one web page that you can retrieve in another page (on the same domain), you can either store it in a cookie or in local storage.

Browsers cache whole web resources (pages, images, scripts, etc...) not individual pieces of data.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for using the local-storage.

here is a nice little plugin for using the localStorage with jQuery (including docs): http://upstatement.com/blog/2012/01/jquery-local-storage-done-right-and-easy/

this plugin uses cookies as a fallback for browsers which do not support the localStorage-feature